# How to handle a Shiny plot that isn't ready to display yet

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Consider the following toy example

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyWidgets)

data(mtcars)
cylinders <- unique(mtcars$cyl)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("MWE"),

    # Sidebar  
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          pickerInput("cylinders",
                        "Number of cylinders:",
                        choices = cylinders,
                        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                        multiple = TRUE)
        ),

        # Show a plot
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("mpg")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required
server <- function(input, output) {

    
    output$mpg <- renderPlot({
        plotData <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == input$cylinders)
        mpgPlot <- plotData %>% ggplot(aes(x=hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
        print(mpgPlot)
        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When you first run the app you see

[image]

Is there an "elegant" way to have something other than an error message in the plot output until the plot is ready?

In my actual case, I need the user to make a selection from a selectInput.  Based on that selection, a set of allowable values will be added to a second selectInput.  Once a choice is made from that list, the plot can be produced...

Comment: Your problem is that the `renderPlot` blocks is firing before `input$cylinders` exists, therefore you're effectively doing `cyl == NULL`. You can use `req(input$cylinders)` to remedy this.

Comment: This might just be a problem in your toy example, but the test in `filter(cyl == input$cylinders)` should be `filter(cyl %in% input$cylinders)`, because `input$cylinders` might be a vector, not just a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [req() function](https://shiny.posit.co/r/reference/shiny/0.14.2/req.html)

> provides that values are available before proceeding with a
> calculation or action. If any of the given values is not truthy, the
> operation is stopped by raising a "silent" exception

Applying this to your plot as follows will silently halt the plot render until such time that `input$cylinders` is selected by the user and becomes "truthy"

```
output$mpg <- renderPlot({
    req(input$cylinders)
    plotData <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == input$cylinders)
    mpgPlot <- plotData %>% ggplot(aes(x=hp, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
    print(mpgPlot)
    
  })
```

Comment: Didn't know `req()` was a thing!  Thanks!